# how to express division in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to express relational algebra division in my sql. It should be done somehow using the not exists operator. For example the task is "Find the apples which are all bought  by Tom". Show the names. This is division. I have come up with the following query but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT S.name
FROM Apples S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT E.pId
                      from Products E
                     where NOT EXISTS (SELECT L.pId
                                        FROM Buyers L
                                        where E.pId = L.pId
                                        AND S.mId = E.mId
                                        AND L.name = 'Tom'));
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To do that only using EXISTS you could try:

```
SELECT S.NAME
FROM Apples S
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Products E
    WHERE S.mId = E.mId
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Buyers L
        WHERE E.pId = L.pId
          AND L.NAME <> 'Tom'
        )
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Buyers L
        WHERE E.pId = L.pId
          AND L.NAME = 'Tom'
        )
    );
```

This will do:
Get all apples that EXIST in PRODUCTS, but NOT EXISTS any buyer with Name <> 'TOM', but at the same time, it EXISTS a buyer with Name 'Tom' . Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Filipe. Thank you for your reply but I need to use only "NOT EXIST" everywhere as I have done it but my query does not give me the results I want. That's why I wonder whether I have got any error?.
Thank you

Comment: can you share a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlifddle.com) with the tables and sample data to mess a bit with it?